# How should Poetry scripts used in the build process be stored in the project?

Tags: python, package, directory-structure, python-poetry, build-script

Let's say that you're using Poetry to manage a Python PyPI package. As it stands, your project has a `Makefile` that contains procedures for managing the installation, unit testing, and linting of your project. However, since this goes against the spirit of Poetry where you ideally have one configuration file to rule them all (`pyproject.toml`), and because said `Makefile` can be annoying on Windows builds, you would like to instead move the `Makefile` functionality to be managed by Poetry directly by making use of [Poetry's support for `setuptools` scripts](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#scripts).

Here's an example of such a `Makefile`:

```
PYMODULE := awesome_sauce
TESTS := tests
INSTALL_STAMP := .install.stamp
POETRY := $(shell command -v poetry 2> /dev/null)
MYPY := $(shell command -v mypy 2> /dev/null)

.DEFAULT_GOAL := help

.PHONY: all
all: install lint test

.PHONY: help
help:
    @echo "Please use 'make <target>', where <target> is one of"
    @echo ""
    @echo "  install     install packages and prepare environment"
    @echo "  lint        run the code linters"
    @echo "  test        run all the tests"
    @echo "  all         install, lint, and test the project"
    @echo "  clean       remove all temporary files listed in .gitignore"
    @echo ""
    @echo "Check the Makefile to know exactly what each target is doing."
    @echo "Most actions are configured in 'pyproject.toml'."

install: $(INSTALL_STAMP)
$(INSTALL_STAMP): pyproject.toml
    @if [ -z $(POETRY) ]; then echo "Poetry could not be found. See https://python-poetry.org/docs/"; exit 2; fi
    $(POETRY) run pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
    $(POETRY) install
    touch $(INSTALL_STAMP)

.PHONY: lint
lint: $(INSTALL_STAMP)
    # Configured in pyproject.toml
    # Skips mypy if not installed
    @if [ -z $(MYPY) ]; then echo "Mypy not found, skipping..."; else echo "Running Mypy..."; $(POETRY) run mypy $(PYMODULE) $(TESTS); fi
    @echo "Running Flake8..."; $(POETRY) run pflake8 # This is not a typo
    @echo "Running Pylint..."; $(POETRY) run pylint $(PYMODULE)

.PHONY: test
test: $(INSTALL_STAMP)
    # Configured in pyproject.toml
    $(POETRY) run pytest

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    # Delete all files in .gitignore
    git clean -Xdf
```

But then, you face another problem; due to how these scripts operate, they're expected to be in a package or module of their own, so the first idea would be to simply include the scripts as part of the project package itself:

```
awesome_sauce
 ┣ awesome_sauce
 ┃ ┣ poetry_scripts
 ┃ ┃ ┣ __init__.py
 ┃ ┃ ┣ run_unit_tests.py
 ┃ ┃ ┗ run_linters.py
 ┃ ┣ __init__.py
 ┃ ┗ sauce.py
 ┣ docs
 ┣ tests
 ┣ .gitignore
 ┣ poetry.lock
 ┗ pyproject.toml
```

In this case, you could add the following to `pyproject.toml`

```
[tool.poetry.scripts]
tests = 'awesome_sauce.poetry_scripts.run_unit_tests:main'
linters = 'awesome_sauce.poetry_scripts.run_linters:main'
```

and they could be run as

```sh
poetry run tests
poetry run linters
```

But this isn't ideal; now your build configuration is part of the package and presumably goes straight into production, unless you pull off something fancy during the CI/CD process. It's dead weight to the end-users, and needlessly adds stuff to the package namespace.

Then, another idea would be to have everything in a top-level script:

```
awesome_sauce
 ┣ awesome_sauce
 ┃ ┣ __init__.py
 ┃ ┗ sauce.py
 ┣ docs
 ┣ tests
 ┣ .gitignore
 ┣ poetry.lock
 ┣ poetry_scripts.py
 ┗ pyproject.toml
```

which would change the lines in `pyproject.toml` to

```
[tool.poetry.scripts]
tests = 'poetry_scripts:run_unit_tests'
linters = 'poetry_scripts:run_linters'
```

but this isn't necessarily ideal either, because now you potentially have a relatively lengthy script sitting at the project root, and it can be subjectively ugly. Though at least now it shouldn't be part of the production package, which is a net gain.

These two approaches could be combined, and the script package in the first version would simply be moved to the root, meaning the project now consists of two different packages.

```
awesome_sauce
 ┣ awesome_sauce
 ┃ ┣ __init__.py
 ┃ ┗ sauce.py
 ┣ docs
 ┣ poetry_scripts
 ┃ ┣ __init__.py
 ┃ ┣ run_unit_tests.py
 ┃ ┗ run_linters.py
 ┣ tests
 ┣ .gitignore
 ┣ poetry.lock
 ┗ pyproject.toml
```

```
[tool.poetry.scripts]
tests = 'poetry_scripts.run_unit_tests:main'
linters = 'poetry_scripts.run_linters:main'
```

but it isn't clear whether this is a better approach.

Does a consensus exist for handling the Poetry/`setuptools` scripts within a given project? If so, I don't believe that has been previously documented in public.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe there is a clear consensus on this.

However I've been working on a solution called [Poe the Poet](https://github.com/nat-n/poethepoet) which is intended to be a better fit than *make* for most projects; it integrates nicely with poetry, works seamlessly cross-platform (depending how you define your tasks), and it's self documenting.

Firstly, it's important to be aware that I don't think `[tool.poetry.scripts]` is what you want at all, because anything you define there will actually be installed into the PATH of any environment where your package is installed!

What poethepoet allows you to do is define tasks in your pyproject.toml like so:

```
[tool.poe.tasks]
test = "pytest -v"
```

Which can then be invoked with the poe CLI tool like

```sh
poe test tests/features # extra args are appended to the command
```

Or if you want to define the task logic in a python module (and make the task self documenting while you're at it) you can do something like:

```
[tool.poe.tasks.lint]
script = "poetry_scripts.run_linters:main"
help   = "Check code style and such"
```

Running `poe` without any arguments prints documentation including available tasks and their help messages.

As for the project layout, I'd suggest putting all your python code under `./src` to get something like:

```
awesome_sauce
 ┣ src
 ┃ ┣ awesome_sauce
 ┃ ┃ ┣ __init__.py
 ┃ ┃ ┗ sauce.py
 ┃ ┣ scripts
 ┃ ┃ ┣ __init__.py
 ┃ ┃ ┣ run_unit_tests.py
 ┃ ┃ ┗ run_linters.py
 ┣ docs
 ┣ tests
 ┣ .gitignore
 ┣ poetry.lock
 ┗ pyproject.toml
```

and then setting the following in the poetry section of your pyproject.toml so that awesome_sauce is included in your build, but everything else in src will be ignored by `poetry build`

```
packages = [{include = "awesome_sauce", from = "src"}]
```

It also works as a poetry plugin.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not entirely on board with this suggestion. First, it requires adding a third-party dependency that hasn't been verified to be safe to the build process which may not be viable in company projects that do heavy auditing on dependencies (including mine). Second, I believe it to be non-standard or old-fashioned to use `src` as the project directory in modern Python libraries.

Comment: If your toolset is restricted then that makes things harder... Probably calling commands or python scripts from your Makefile is the best you can do. As for using the src layout, I don't know about it being non-standard or old-fashioned, but it recommended [by pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/goodpractices.html), [supported](https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/) and [used](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry) by poetry, and has [some concrete advantages](https://hynek.me/articles/testing-packaging/). And I believe it helps in your situation.

Comment: compare contrast poe vs invoke?

Comment: @JohnVandivier key high level differences here are that 1) poe works seamlessly with poetry out of the box (no need to or abuse `[tool.poetry.scripts]` or `poetry run` everything), 2) poe tasks are defined in pyproject.toml and can take many forms, whereas invoke tasks are python functions in tasks.py.